# Why click event for file browse window is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`<input>` for select images:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control forminputs files photoimg" multiple name="photoimg[]" placeholder="Choose 3 image files" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" id="photoimg" />
```

I am trying to select at least 3 images. If it is exceeded 3, then it alerts "please select 3" and again automatically opens file browse window.

Up to `alert` everything works fine but after that file browse window is not opening.

JS code:

```
$('#photoimg').change(function() {
    var files = this.files.length;
    if (files > 3)
    {
        alert("Please select 3 images only(png/jpg)");
        document.getElementById("photoimg").click();
    } 
});
```

tried with this.click() and  $('#photoimg').click();.

```
 $('#photoimg').click(function() {
     alert("clicked");
     });
```

to test it click event was taken, click event was working but still file browse was not working.
Why it is not working?

Comment: instead of `if(files>3)` try  `if(paresInt(files)>3)`

Comment: @Kartikeya  but alert is working

Comment: instead of `document.getElementById("photoimg").click();` try `$(this).click()`

Comment: Do you get any console error?

Comment: @Kartikeya tried with this.click() and $('#photoimg').click(); but not working.

Comment: @jaya AFAIK, you cannot do it without any user interaction (click)

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the working demo
$('#photoimg').change(function() {
var files = this.files.length;
if (files != 3)
{
    alert("Please select 3 images only(png/jpg)");
    document.getElementById("photoimg").click();
} 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/4fbz5f1m/4/

Comment: upto alert it is working fine but not opened file browse window

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform click event for file input because of security reasons. You can do that by creating custom element which behave like file input element.

Comment: `You can do that by creating custom element which behave like file input element` How that's relevant to OP's question? Any sample?